# Can we ask for the enduser for the facebook username and password to connect to our Website

Tags: facebook

I have a strange demand where i will prompt for username and password of facebook to the end users to connect to my website.

I very well know that this is wrong as there is something called Facebook connect button but is it possible?

If not possible how can i use facebook connect button. I have gone through numerous example but none of them is clear. They are asking for some API keys etc i dont know what it is?

Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: I'll point you to the direction of: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: I will appreciate if the persons downvoting mention the reasons also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's against the [Facebook Platform Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 2 . You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or
>   collects Facebook usernames or passwords.

Why would you want to do that?

Comment: i dont want to do it but the PSDs i got to create the Project have it thats why i asked this question, by the way thanks for the answer

Comment: Tell the person who created the PSDs to update them to use the Connect button. You can't do something that's not allowed, just because of some designs!

Answer (score 0):

No you should not ask them for their username / password as it will be no good to you and you will be responsible for this data and making sure it is not lost / stolen etc.

simply google'ing "facebook api key" linked to a website and 2 youtube videos detailing how to obtain it:

http://help.webscribble.com/display/jconnector/Getting+the+Facebook+Connect+API+Key